# Removing Extra Space After Player

Tags: css

I want to display embeded video in my page in 720px x 405 px so I reduced the default size defined in theme which was 922px but after making changes there is an extra space which is creating an issue and I want to remove this space. Here is the screenshot which I got while using Firebug :-

link :- http://personal.t15.org/Untitled-2.jpg

link :-  http://bit.ly/129HyJm

Can anyone tell me how to remove this space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS:

```
.fluid-width-video-wrapper {
    position: relative !important;
    bottom: -90px !important;
}

.embed-vimeo {
    margin-top: -90px !important;
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, I'm sincerely grateful to you. Can you do me a favor, is there a way to contact you , I wanna ask something which I can't post here?

Comment: @Robbins Please, write your e-mail address in your profile, so I can contact you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
.embed-vimeo iframe, .embed-youtube iframe{max-height:auto !important;}
```

Comment: As I mentioned I want to display video in this size 720px x 405px and the code which you wrote removes the extra space but increases the video player size to 922px wide. Could you tell me a code which keeps video player size to 720px x 405px and at the same time removes the extra space as well.